# Como obtener de resultado el valor secundario a partir del primario en Diccionario en Vb.Net (LINQ)

Tags: vb.net, linq

Llegado al caso que tengo el siguiente diccionario

```
Dim x As New Dictionary(Of integer, String)
        x.Add(1, "uno")
        x.Add(2, "dos")
        x.Add(3, "tres")
```

Y en ves de obtener el valor del ítem  desde el valor principal como es a continuación:

```
    MsgBox("Valor de 2:" & x.Item(2))
```

Quisiera obtener desde el otro lado el ítem, un ejemplo seria el siguiente:

```
    MsgBox("Valor de 2:" & x.Item("dos"))
```

Quiero obtener un valor Integer, desde un string, pero esto da error, porque el ítem principal no es String, sino Integer, quisiera saber como puedo obtener el valor principal desde el secundario
He sabido que se puede obtener mediante LINQ!, pero no se como se puede llegar a realizar.Alguien sabe?, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Qué intenta cuando un valor aparece en más de uno clave?

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario, lo que decís es si, aparece más de un valor repetido? en mi diccionario no tengo valores repetidos, porque son objetos independientes, no se repiten, Se que se puede realizar con algo llamado "linq" pero no lo entiendo bien yo

Comment: Bueno, que pasa si el data sea x.add(1, "Perro"), x.add(2, "Perro"), x.add(3, "Gato"), y busca "Perro"?  Queire el primér clave?  El último?  Ambos?  Un error?